# How do I delete a shared parameter in Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: testcase, mtm

We are using Microsoft Test Manager 2015 Update 1. I created a couple of shared parameters to see how they work.

How do you delete them? I can make them inactive, but they still display in the list of available shared parameters. I don't see a delete button and when I searched online I found nothing about it.

Comment: shared parameters..Never heard about that in MSTM.Are you in to shared  steps?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use Team Services with MTM. In that case, let us get the basics right.

Shared Steps are another [Work Item Type](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/guidance/agile-process-workflow) and Work Items can manully be deleted using the [command line tool.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items#permanently-delete-work-items-command-line-tool)

I guess the above links would help you get started.

Note : I assumed certain things while writing the answer. Please let me know if my assumptions are wrong.